# Why mongoose abortTransaction() not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

- MacOS: 10.15.5
- NodeJS: 10.16.3
- Mongoose: 5.8, 5.9
- MongoDB: 4.0.3

I have next code:

```
import User from 'models/user'

const session = await User.startSession()
session.startTransaction()

try{
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'test@test.com' })
  user.email = 'test111@test111.com'
  await user.save()
  
  throw
}
catch(e){
  await session.abortTransaction()
}
finally{
  await session.endSession()
}
```

But in database I see:

> "email": "test111@test111.com'"

**Why abortTransaction() does not working as expected? What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: @D.SM, Transactions in Mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html MongodDB replica set launched using bitnami-docker-mongodb: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb

Comment: You are not passing session to find, or to save.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the session to the DB methods involved in the transaction:

```
 const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'test@test.com' }, null, { session })
 user.email = 'test111@test111.com'
 await user.save({ session })
```

Comment: Or you have User.findOne().session(session)...etc.